# PHP see POST/GET values made to script dynamically

Tags: php, post, terminal

I've been testing a PHP script that I'm posting values to every few seconds (latitude and longitude to be specific) and am wondering if there's an easier way to see what values are being sent to the script. Right now I'm writing the data to a txt file on my server, and refreshing the page every so often to see what values have been posted recently. Is there a way to just see what's going on behind the scenes (in terminal, perhaps)?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this something you want to do just for debugging purposes or for production environment? Also, what could be easier than something you've already made and is working? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's of course `print_r()` to output it directly:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

then there's [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), an extension to Firebug, that allows sending messages to Firebug's console.

Both should be enabled only in a development environment!

Comment: +1 FirePHP. Keeps the source pure (info is put into headers).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already writing to a text file, ssh to the server, and `tail -f logfile.txt`

If you are running on windows, you can install the [gnu utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and do the same thing.